# Firebase: AngularFire Seed won't login

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Keeps showing:

```
Please configure app/js/config.js before running!
```

I updated my Firebase URL in config.js, enabled email/password and anonymous login in Forge.

Even changed text in the above error msg to:

```
"TEST Please configure app/js/config.js before running!"
```

, in app.js -- and my modified text doesn't show up even. Why? I restarted the web server between changes.

```
node scripts/web-server.js
```

Crazy, I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I also had the ZIP archive in my Trash folder on Mac OS, somehow my console was in my Trash path, (no friggin idea how it got there, as I never cd'd to it), hence changes to my main folder weren't getting detected by the web server running on my Trash folder. Stupid user error -)